# Is there an equivalent of Hammerspoon (macOS) for Linux?

Tags: linux, window-management

I like [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org) for macOS, and I want to switch to Linux.  Is there something equivalent to Hammerspoon for Linux?

Answer (score 6):

#### Hammerspoon offers automation where macOS doesn't

[Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org) is kind of a grab-bag of different capabilities, at least based on what its inbuilt APIs provide. On Mac OS it's a useful tool to work around the lack of open-source core functionality in the operating system and provide some prescriptive configuration.

#### Linux has other native ways to automate

On Linux, frankly, it's less necessary. Most of the capabilities can be achieved with other software, depending on what you use Hammerspoon for. For example, on my Mac I use Hammerspoon as a window manager to provide hotkeys, window rearrangement keys, etc. - on Linux I simply use [i3](https://i3wm.org/), which is superior anyway.

*Source*: I use both a Mac and Linux on a daily basis.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for the heads up. I'm thinking about switching to Linux but the only thing stopping me is HammerSpoon and how darn convenient it is.

Comment: @safdfsgasdfg it might help if you can specify *what* in Hammerspoon you use. Hammerspoon can do lots of different things, most of them unrelated.

Comment: Oddly enough, this answer was copy/pasted without attribution into https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF98UIp2jbo